# Verify error during jboss deployment. How to resolve this issue?

Tags: java, deployment, jboss-eap-7

When I deploy my application in Jboss, I'm getting the following error

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-6) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."test.ear"."hello.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."test.ear"."hello.war".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "hello.war" of deployment "test.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:172)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEE0024: Could not configure component HelloWorld
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:106)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:165)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.jboss.classfilewriter.ClassFile.define(ClassFile.java:313)
    at org.jboss.invocation.proxy.AbstractClassFactory.defineClass(AbstractClassFactory.java:160)
    at org.jboss.invocation.proxy.AbstractProxyFactory.getCachedMethods(AbstractProxyFactory.java:146)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$DefaultConfigurator.configure(ViewDescription.java:196)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.DefaultComponentViewConfigurator.configure(DefaultComponentViewConfigurator.java:67)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:92)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.classfilewriter.ClassFile.define(ClassFile.java:308)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class com.test.java.HelloWorldImpl$$$view1 overrides final method getDetails.(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    ... 16 more
```

Note: class HelloWorldImpl is not overriding final method getDetails. it is just calling its super class final method getDetails.

Code:

```
class HelloWorldImpl extends Hello{
...
public void display() { 
...     
 Foo fooObj = (Foo)getDetails("test");
...
}
}               

class Hello{
public final Object getDetails(String id){
...
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show us you code part from HelloWorldImpl ?

Comment: Sure. I have updated the few lines of code by editing the above post

Answer (score 0):

The HelloWorldImpl is not proxyable because it has a final method inherited from Hello.

Nonproxyable classes can't have an scope other than `@Dependent`.

If you can't to use the `@Dependent` scope, you could extract an interface with the methods you need from HelloWorldImpl, and change the injection point to the interface type.

Check then WELD documentation referring this situation and workarounds: https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html#_client_proxies